# Connect to a server using SSH and a pem / key with golang

Tags: ssh, go

I'm trying to connect to an amazon AWS linux server with a key using the [ssh][1] package of Go programming language. However the package documentation is a bit cryptic/confusing. Does anyone know how to connect through ssh using a key  or at least if it's possible ? What bothers me is that in the [Dial][3] example it says

```
// An SSH client is represented with a ClientConn. Currently only
// the "password" authentication method is supported.
```

I basically want to mimic the ssh -i x.pem root@server.com behavior and execute a command inside the server ( e.g. `whoami` )

Comment: a panic implies you're ignoring an error somewhere (or setting a defer before checking an error). we need some code to know what you're doing.

Comment: @JimB I've added some code. I think I've checked all the errors. The defer to close the session was set after error checking

Comment: your panic is because you're calling `defer session.Close()` on where session is nil. `t.Error(err)` doesn't return early.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to use `ssh.PublicKeys` to turn a list of `ssh.Signers` into an `ssh.AuthMethod`. You can use `ssh.ParsePrivateKey` to get a `Signer` from the pem bytes, or if you need to use an rsa, dsa or ecdsa private key, you can give those to `ssh.NewSignerFromKey`.

Here's an example fleshed out a bit with Agent support too (since using an agent is usually the next step after simply using a key file).

```
sock, err := net.Dial("unix", os.Getenv("SSH_AUTH_SOCK"))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

agent := agent.NewClient(sock)

signers, err := agent.Signers()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// or get the signer from your private key file directly
// signer, err := ssh.ParsePrivateKey(pemBytes)
// if err != nil {
//     log.Fatal(err)
// }

auths := []ssh.AuthMethod{ssh.PublicKeys(signers...)}

cfg := &ssh.ClientConfig{
    User: "username",
    Auth: auths,
}
cfg.SetDefaults()

client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", "aws-hostname:22", cfg)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

session, err = client.NewSession()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

log.Println("we have a session!")

...
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the code. How do I pass the key file ( e.g. mykey.pem ) or key content ? Signer seems to be an interface. I have the keys stored in a db

Comment: I added a note about using `ParsePrivateKey` to get a signer from the pem bytes.

Comment: why do I need ``agent`` ? it seems declared but not used as I use ``signers, err := ssh.ParsePrivateKey(cl.Key)``

Comment: you don't *need* to use an agent in your program, but since you *should* be using one in general (your keys are all safely encrypted, right?), it's usually the next "how to" request after using a plain private key file.

Comment: @JimB Your example is not clear, I guess you are relying on some defaults, any SSH involves two keys, private and public key, your example only uses the private key, the public key is retrieved through some black magic using ssh.PublicKeys, but the point is, how do I specify where the public key is instead of relying on the default behaviour of ssh.PublicKey? which if i am not wrong will just try to locate the public key on the default location.

Comment: @Melardev, no, authentication only uses the private key; but since the public key can be derived from the private key it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 15):

Here is an example to run **ls** remotely using your "plain private key file".

```
    pemBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/location/to/YOUR.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    signer, err := ssh.ParsePrivateKey(pemBytes)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("parse key failed:%v", err)
    }
    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: "ubuntu",
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{ssh.PublicKeys(signer)},
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
    }
    conn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", "yourhost.com:22", config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("dial failed:%v", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    session, err := conn.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("session failed:%v", err)
    }
    defer session.Close()
    var stdoutBuf bytes.Buffer
    session.Stdout = &stdoutBuf
    err = session.Run("ls -l")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Run failed:%v", err)
    }
    log.Printf(">%s", stdoutBuf)
```

Comment: any idea why it might see dial failed:ssh: must specify HostKeyCallback